# Scrolling function (from Link to Section Tag) not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scroll

I'm writing a new 1 Site WebPage in HTML5. I have a menu on top in the "header".

If you click on one of the menu links it should smoothly scroll down/up to the corresponding point (a "section" with id). I found a nice example here and I included it into my HTML File. So it looks like this:

**UPDATED FILES** (index.html, start.css, scroll.js)

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>Home</title>

    <!-- Layout -->
    <link href="layout/start.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Font -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/info.js"></script>
    <script src="script/scroll.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Header/Navi -->
    <header>
        <div id="header_holder">
            <div id="navi">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>                           
                <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>                       
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>               
                <li>About</li>                                          
                <li>Contact</li>                                        
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Body -->
    <section id="home">
        <div id="pages_holder">
            Home
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="news">
        <div id="pages_holder">
            News
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="projects">
        <div id="pages_holder">
            Projects
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about">
        <div id="pages_holder">
            About
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="contact">
        <div id="pages_holder">
            Contact
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div id="footer_holder">
            2014 | 94.247.218.142
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

start.css:

```
    /* <-- Start Layout --> */
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* --Link Decoration-- */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

a:visited {
    color: #000;
}

/* --Header-- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    background-color: #4CACE7;
}

#header_holder {
    height: 100px;
    width: 810px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

/* --Navi-- */
#navi {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#navi li {
    height: 100px;
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

#navi li:hover {
    height: 96px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid white;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

#navi a {
    color: #fff;
}

#navi a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* --Body-- */
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* Pages */
section {
    height: 774px;
}

#pages_holder {
    height: 100%;
    width: 810px; /* Total length Body */
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#home {
    padding-top: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#news {
    background-color: #223759;
}

#projects {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#about {
    background-color: #223759;
}

#contact {
    background-color: #fff;
}

/* --Footer-- */
footer {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px; /* Border 4px */
    background-color: #4CACE7;
}
#footer_holder {
    height: 50px;
    width: 810px; /* Total length Body */
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding-top: 0.4%;
    padding-bottom: 0.4%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

scroll.js:

```
//Scrolling Animation

var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function () {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - 100
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

For testing I removed the include tag which includes the "scroll.js" -> there is no difference!
So i added this in the end of the scroll.js file to see if jQuery is loaded:

```
 if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert("jQuery Version " + jQuery.fn.jquery + " loaded!");
 }
```

The alert was showing... so i think jQuery is running how i shoud...(?)

I createt also a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ULeuu/83/ where I entered my data (copy&paste) and I had to see that it's works like it shoud!
**UPDATE: NEW JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/6a8vuae7/2/

Can everybody please help me? I have no idea what is wrong!

**UPDATE:**

I copied my HTML & CSS & JS File to JSFiddle and edited only the HTML File (like removing html tags and things it said to remove) and it works there. But it still won't work on my WebServer... I compared the code in I have not found any Syntax mistakes.

So Please help I despair on this problem!

Comment: If it works in the fiddle but not on your page, then there's probably something else in your code that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must bring the html5 `<header>` tag into the body:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/scroll.js"></script>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="navi">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>                           
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>                       
            <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>               
            <li>About</li>                                          
            <li>Contact</li>                                        
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="home">
        <div id="pages_holder">
            Home
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="news">
        <div id="pages_holder">
            News
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- More Sections... -->
</body>
```

you've probably mistaken it with the `<head>` tag which must be outside the body!

**Why it works on fiddle?**

well the answer is because jsfiddle wraps your whole code inside a `<body>` tag, so it seems as though the `<header>` tag **IS** actually inside the `<body>` tag!

**UPDATE:**

how about if you change the click function to this?

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - 100
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx for answering... I moved the Body tag before the header (added in post above) but it is still not working :/

Comment: so i updated the index.html above...
(still no scrolling effects)

Comment: just change the jQuery? -> no reaction b klicking on a link... also not on JSFiddle

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong here, but I'm 100% sure the code is fine!

Comment: hmm... Could it be my Webserver or just my browser??

Comment: no, because as you mentioned, jQuery is actually running! maybe forgot to put a `,` or a `;` or a miss-spelling or a typo is causing the problem!

Comment: Yea this alert is working... Now I'm going trought all to see if there is someting wrong in my syntax...

Comment: I found no mistakes... I updated the Files abouve. They are now accectualy like them on my server. STILL NOT WORKING :/

Comment: I can not figure it out, but I have an idea! try testing a jQuery function like, `alert($('a').eq(0).html())` and see if it works. actually `alert('ok')` is not using jQuery, it is pure JS, so this way we can find out whether jQuery library is loaded or not!

Comment: I'm not sure how to include this into my code... Shoud I add this to my scroll.js...? If yes, where?

Comment: have you used a ready function for your code? read this article, this may solve your problem! http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Thank you sooo much man! I added "$( document ).ready(function()" and now it works..! Thx :D